# Lenovo Legion 7 AMD - Keyboard Issue

Tags: keyboard, troubleshooting, lenovo-laptop, keystrokes, issue-tracking

My model is Lenovo Legion 7 16ARHA7 | BIOS K9CN44WW | Machine type 82UH |

On my Windows 11 installation, after some updates, certain keys stopped working after a reboot. I had to wait for like 5-10 minutes, and then everything was okay. However, this was happening out of the blue and only affected the keys qweruiop (first row).

I've tried everything in software: Changing/installing/uninstalling keyboard drivers, enabling or disabling various HID devices, but no matter what I do, the problem remains.

I installed a Windows 10 version, and now after some reboots and updates, the keys are not working again. This time it's the first column like qaz!!

I've attempted to disable the HYDRA keys service, and in general, I've tried to find a solution, but I can't. I have experience with computers, but something tells me it's not the hardware because it works fine most of the time, especially with a fresh install or if I wait some time. If it were the keyboard, it wouldn't work at all after some point.

Now I'm on a fresh Windows 10 installation, and I still feel that something is not right. I even changed the settings not to put it to sleep.

I believed it was the updates from Windows 11. That's why I installed Windows 10 but even now the keys are randomly stop working and I have to wait some time. In windows 11 the time was 5 to 10 minutes. Now it's even more but it doesn't occur so often. I think it happens more when I shut down the PC for many hours during the night.

When I use it during the day it works fine. When I shutdown the laptop and wake up the next day the keys are not working.

Is it the drivers? Is it something affecting the input services? Is it Lenovo's power plans? Is it Hydra keys drivers? Is it all together? I have tried installing the image from Lenovo support and a clean installation of both windows 11 and 10.

Comment: You most likely need a new keyboard  (keyboard, cable, backlight)

Comment: An issue that survives a complete reinstallation of Windows suggests the problem is hardware, not software.

Comment: However, try 1. update UEFI ("BIOS") and 2. Make sure Windows Fast Startup is disabled.

Comment: If you try a live usb you can use linux without installing it, and check if the problem also occurs when Windows is out of the picture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB

Comment: I have tried setting a password in Bios in order to check if the keys are responding outside of windows environment and i have obtained some really strange information. The keys are not responding while the laptop is still 'COLD'. This is checked multiple times. Once the laptop is warm (needs some time like 5 to 10 minutes) the keys are alive kn all environments. For example if is cold and run a benchmark the keys will respond faster than idle. This is happening even if they work but close the lid ( no sleep or hibernation) and then open it after a while which has become cold. This is crazy!!